Integrate Uniview CCTV broadcast in Grails Application
We are trying to integrate the CCTV within our internal application (particularly Grails Application) for live broadcasting. With this, anyone who has access to the application can view the live broadcast of CCTV. There should be no restriction for application users to access CCTV.
Currently, we are accessing CCTV broadcasts using the IP address (for example http://192.168.100.1) and logging in by entering the username and credentials in the login page of cctv itself.
We are unable to embed or iframe this URL(ip address) itself since we will face mixed content error as this camera URL(IP) is in http and our application is using SSL(https). Even if we configure SSL in camera, we will face issue because of CORS policy.
Is there any way by which we can integrate the CCTV live broadcast into the webpage with ease maintaining all aspects of security? The username and password of CCTV should not be visible to end users(application users).
I tried to embed the login page of cctv within my web page and use JS to submit form. But this seems impossible.

Use rtsp or the API what your cctv provide :)
